# SwiftUI Datepicker displaying language in English Only?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am Japanese

I want to change the date selection language of the calendar to Japanese using DatePicker.
I read the Document, but there was no such setting, so if you know anyone, I would like to know.

For example, in the image example, I want to convert February to Japanese.

[image: DatePicker Image]

Comment: Is your app localized for Japanese? Is your device configured as Japanese? Did you try reading the documentation? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615995-locale

Comment: Do you want to use Japanese calendar or Japanese localization for the titles (while using Gregorian calendar)?

Comment: @matt

>Is your app localized for Japanese?
>Is your device configured as Japanese?

No

Thank you!

Comment: @user28434
>Do you want to use Japanese calendar or Japanese localization for the titles
Yes!

Comment: @mikami, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236076/answering-a-multiple-choice-question-with-yes/236077

Comment: @user28434
Thank you

Answer (score 13):

you can do this pt is for Portuguese:

```
DatePicker("Please enter date",selection: $wakeUp, in: Date()...)
            .labelsHidden()
            .environment(\.locale, Locale.init(identifier: "pt"))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
.environment(\.locale, #YourLocale#)

You can use this method.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
struct DatePicker2: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var date: Date

    private let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIDatePicker {
//        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        let loc = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
        datePicker.locale = loc
        datePicker.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.changed(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return datePicker
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIDatePicker, context: Context) {
        datePicker.date = date
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> DatePicker2.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(date: $date)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        private let date: Binding<Date>

        init(date: Binding<Date>) {
            self.date = date
        }

        @objc func changed(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
            self.date.wrappedValue = sender.date
        }
    }
}
```

I modified this code from here :

[SwiftUI: how to create custom UIDatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59849818/swiftui-how-to-create-custom-uidatepicker)

Greetings from Uruguay!

Answer (score 2):

Date Picker locale all language:

```
DatePicker("", selection: $selectedTime, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: [.date,.hourAndMinute]).environment(\.locale, Locale.init(identifier: String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0].prefix(2))))
```