# Approach to use a SwiftUI view together with a UIView

Tags: uikit, swiftui

I'm using a 3rd party library developed with `UIKit`. It's API needs a reference to a UIView.

How can I use this library inside SwiftUI? And how can I convert a SwiftUI view to a UIView?

I've tried creating a `UIViewRepresentable` like this:

```
struct SomeView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let contentViewController: UIViewController

    init<Content: View>(contentView: Content) {
        self.contentViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIKitView {

        // Whatever I do here doesn't work. Frame is always 0

        contentViewController.loadViewIfNeeded() 
        contentViewController.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        contentViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        print(contentViewController.view.frame)

        let uikitView = UIKitView()
        uikitView.show(contentViewController.view)
        return popover
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIKitView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You can see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59853272/12299030) the simple case of construction `UIViewRepresentable` and its usage in post question use-case.

Comment: @Asperi i don't think you read my question in entirety